# return ajax.done data gives error on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have data in my ajax.done and it bugs on jquery. 
i googled on it and cant find anything.

what to do?

```
function select_aragement(arragament){
  var arrst = arragament;
  var arrsplit = arrst.split("|");
  var periode = arrsplit[0];
  var id = arrsplit[1];
  var postsjson;
  var test= $.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    url: 'ajax/prijzen.php',
    data: { id: id, periode: periode },
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function (vis) {
    console.log(vis);
    postsjson = $.parseJSON(vis);
  });
  return  postsjson;
}
```

Comment: what `console.log(vis);` gives you ? Where is the problem ????

Comment: Are you sure that your data is `vis` rather than `vis.d`?

Comment: vis givesback an object

Comment: The `dataType: 'json'` tells jQuery that it's expecting a JSON response, and it implicitly parses the response text as JSON to pass the object/array defined to your `done` function. You shouldn't (and, I suspect, can't without producing an error) then pass that to `$.parseJSON()`. It's meaningless, because `vis` isn't a string, it's an actual object.

Comment: Oke! thx Anthony. But how can i return that object i have the code in a way that it will return a string (need object/array). Or an error

Comment: @BartKlaster You shouldn't be returning anything. I've added an answer that explains the execution flow when dealing with AJAX requests. You could, if you wanted/needed to, store the result in a variable that's visible in the full scope of your code and then use it inside functions that are called **after** the AJAX call has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be attempting to return anything from a callback function because the returned value doesn't go anywhere meaningful. Instead you simply *use* the response from the AJAX request inside that callback function.

Let's say you have this code:

```
function bar() {
var myObject = foo();

// do something with myObject
}

function foo() {
    var bar; // 1

    var xhr = $.ajax({
        url: yourUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            some: 'data'
        }
    }); // 2

    xhr.done(function(yourObject) {
        bar = yourObject; // 5
    }); // 3

    return bar; // 4
}

bar();
```

The comments inside the `foo` function indicate the order in which those statements execute. So you declare a variable `bar`, declare a variable `xhr` that has a Deferred object, attach a `done` handler to it with a callback function, return the value of `bar`, **then** the value of `bar` is set (too late - you've already tried to return it).

Inside of your execution of the `bar` function `myObject` is going to be undefined, because the value of `bar` inside the `foo` function wasn't set before the return statement. What you need to do is simply move the `// do something with myObject` code to the callback function, and use `bar` there:

```
function foo() {
    var xhr = $.ajax({
        url: yourUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            some: 'data'
        }
    }); // 1

    xhr.done(function(yourObject) {
        var bar = yourObject; // 4
        // do something with bar
    }); // 2

    // 3 - function execution has finished
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move the return line inside the done section

```
}).done(function (vis) {
     console.log(vis);
     postsjson = $.parseJSON(vis);
     return  postsjson;
});
```

but keep in mind that, being an asynchonous call, so will be your return. My advise would be to pass in a callback.

```
function select_aragement(arragament, callback){
    var arrst = arragament;
    var arrsplit = arrst.split("|");
    var periode = arrsplit[0];
    var id = arrsplit[1];
    var postsjson;
    var test= $.ajax({ 
         type: 'POST',
         async: true,
         url: 'ajax/prijzen.php',
         data: { id: id, periode: periode },
         dataType: 'json'
     });
   test.done(function (vis) {
      console.log(vis);
     postsjson = $.parseJSON(vis);
     callback && callback(postjson);
    });
}
```

And modify your code to use the callback instead of the returned value.

before

```
var postjson=select_aragement(arragament);
...stuff with postjson...
```

after

```
 select_aragement(arragament, function(postjson) {
    ...stuff with postjson...
});
```

Comment: This line: `postsjson = $.parseJSON(vis);` throws an error because `vis` isn't a JSON string. The `dataType: 'json'` on the AJAX call options results in jQuery parsing it to the defined object/array, then passing the result of that operation to the `done` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make the ajax call fire synchronously, for that you need to make the async property false.

```
async: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem :**

Look at the following code :

```
function getValue(){
    var value = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        value = 42;
    }, 1000);

    return value;
}
```

What is the returned value ?

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5uWrZ/1/)

This is your exact same problem with

```
 function select_aragement(arragament){
      var postjson;
      $.ajax(...).done(function(vis){ 
         postjson = vis;
      });

      return postjson;
 }
```

**A solution :**

I imagine you use your function in the following way :

```
var data = select_aragement(arragament);
// do something with data :
$.each(data, function(){
    ....
});
```

You can change `select_aragement`'s code like this :

```
function select_aragement(arragament){
  var arrst = arragament;
  var arrsplit = arrst.split("|");
  var periode = arrsplit[0];
  var id = arrsplit[1];
  var test = $.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST',
      async: true,
      url: 'ajax/prijzen.php',
      data: { id: id, periode: periode },
     dataType: 'json'
  });
  // return the promise which wraps the ajax call
  return test;
}
```

and the calling code like this :

```
// "p" stands for "promise"
var p = function select_aragement(arragament);
p.done(function(data){
    // do something with data :
    $.each(data, function(){
        ....
    });
});
```

or without the local variable :

```
select_aragement(arragament).done(function(data){
    // do something with data :
    $.each(data, function(){
        ....
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use async/await mixed to .done from jQuery like this:

```
async function myasyncfunction(myArgs){
    
    var response = [];

    var req = $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: resquestURL,
        dataType: "json",
    })
    
    await req.done( res => {
        //DO some stuff with your data
           
        for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
            const element = res[index];
            response .push( "some stuff" + element );
        }
    })
    
    return response;
}
```